# Is it possible to query against an element that is a list?

Tags: sql, json, amazon-redshift

I know embedded JSON values are queriable in SQL and redshift. (via functions like `json_extract_path_text`)

But is it possible to have an embedded list of things, and then query against that? e.g. Say I have this table:

```
fruit   people_who_like_it
apples        {[Brian]}
oranges       {[Susan, Brian]}
bananas       {[Freddy]}
```

Is there a way to construct a query to find all fruits that Brian likes?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
SELECT fruit
FROM yourTable
WHERE people_who_like_it LIKE '%Brian%';
```

This should give you any fruit that Brian likes.

UPDATE:

To get results for an exact match for Brian, as pointed out in the comment you could try:

```
 SELECT fruit
 FROM yourTable
 WHERE people_who_like_it LIKE '%[Brian]%'
 OR people_who_like_it LIKE '% Brian]%'
 OR people_who_like_it LIKE '% Brian,%'
 OR people_who_like_it LIKE '%[Brian,%';
```

There are four possibilities that an exact match of Brian could look like, including:

"[Brian]"

" Brian]"  <--preceding space

" Brian,"  <--preceding space

"[Brian,"

Comment: Mm, that would work for this example, so +1. Although if e.g. one person was named 'Cooper' and the other 'Coop' it would break.

Answer (score 0):

If you could convert that string into a JSON string than you can use the 
JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY_ELEMENT_TEXT function:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY_ELEMENT_TEXT.html